# Do we really need to create Stub in java RMI?

Tags: java, rmi

I am reading some RMI document and all the books say that we need to create Stub for the client in order to communicate with the server.
However, I have tried to not create stub and things worked like a charm. I have put the client program on one machine and the server on another, things worked perfectly.
So, what is actually the purpose of creating Stub and do we really need to create one?
Thanks.

Comment: Your books are all very out of date. Stubs became unnecessary in 1.5 in about 2003.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Java 1.5 you don't have to:

> This release adds support for the dynamic generation of stub classes at runtime, **obviating the need to use [...] stub compiler, rmic**, to pregenerate stub classes for remote objects. Note that rmic must still be used to pregenerate stub classes for remote objects that need to support clients running on earlier versions.

From http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/relnotes.html